Future City-Sized Graduate Sorting Process
My story is set in the future where more pressure is set on learning, and schools grow to the size of cities (and for all intents and purposes they are). Each mega campus has everything a city would have, plus an elementary school, middle school, high school, and university (though how they split up education is very different).
Each child is taken from their parents and placed in a school, and their teacher (caretaker) is essentially their parent.
Though they are pretty independent, via the Flynn Effect and pressure to be more street smart students would be smarter than children in our era.
When they reach a certain age, they would graduate from their caretaker, and be sorted out to test which field they would work in, as depending on their results the government would decide where they would work.
If they tested really well in something like research science, they would  be "given" a job at a science facility or research lab. If not, they could look for a job in a more conventional fashion, though only in the field mandated. If they don't test well for anything specific,  they are given a General Field Degree, meaning they can work at any low level job not needing any specific degree.
However, I don't exactly know how this testing process would work. I wouldn't necessarily want written tests, though they could be included as one part of the testing process.

How much do the details matter? Presumably your story or game or whatever won't actually involve the details of any exams or exercises, right? Cos that seems like it would be for a fairly niche audience. Given that your readers and/or players probably aren't interested in taking fictional aptitude tests, just gloss over the details and spend your time on the things that people want to engage with, perhaps?

I'm getting Brave New World vibes from this. Can you explain how contemporary processes are inadequate for your setting? Is it because of scale, or lack of accuracy, or something else?

The number of schools your city needs won’t be much different from real cities. Most people in first world countries already finish high school, and about 1/3rd of them have a university degree. Roughly 10% more elementary/secondary schools and 3 or 4 times as many universities should be sufficient to educate the entire population. Hardly a city sized campus.

There are many different education systems in the world. For example, Germany and France do something sort-of similar to what you want, with pupils being sorted into different streams at the end of primary school (grade 4); some of those streams can give access to university, while other streams are preparations for pactical occupations. The goal is to produce a socially healthy mix of young people joining the workforce. The point being that basic preliminary research is required, and the question does not show the results of your research.

I don't see a question here, or even a question mark.

Please take the time to carefully read our [tour] and the following two help center pages: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]. Your question violates several rules justifying closure. At least (a) the Book Rule, (b) all answers having equal value, and (c) no specific problem to solve. Are you asking about how to design the test? How to analyze the test? How to shuffle students off to another section of your society? How to limit educational options for the sake of your story? Should we deal with special needs? Advanced placement? The bureaucracy? Efficiency? Social/emotional impacts? Etc.

In many respects, this is pretty much what happens in much of the US already. School systems try to separate children from parents; there are already different levels and types of schools; there is already psychological, aptitude and academic testing; many graduates are in fact "given" jobs in their relevant field of study. So, what is your question and how is this related to worldbuilding?

Let the Algorithm Do It
You have a dictatorial setup where you have an Orwellian amount of information about candidates; written tests, private behaviour, dating lives, class choice, and everything their caretaker could report.
A holistic process for determining the best role for a graduate would make much more sense than any sort of exit exam anyway, and given the volume of candidates, an algorithm for job placement could be tuned over several cohorts.
So your graduate scans their ID card and the computer spits out the high-probability job affinities they have associated with them, and they're assigned to whichever of the options needs workers.  Done and dusted.

Resumes, job interviews, hiring agencies and internships
Just like we do it. Have a trained recruiters select them based on interviews and test internships.
Give them a bit of freedom of what fields to apply to, but have them pass interviews and test jobs.
Recruiters will have a great deal of power, and the entire system will be balanced differently, but the basic mechanisms to select competency will be the same.
